# Vivado VDMA: How to use it?

Tags: xilinx, vivado, dma

I have my own IP block with 24 bits input/output axi stream type.
It is an image processing ip. Thus, it should be connected by VDMA.

I tried to configure VDMA accroding to the example and datasheet.
However, I still cannot configure it correctly.

Could you help me by explain about VDMA?

Comment: Are your problems on hardware or on software side?

Comment: I am sure there is a Xilinx guide for this try to find it. This forum is more suitable for your question: https://forums.xilinx.com/